# Ionic Framework - How can I submit a form with dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ionic-framework, submit

I have some texboxes which are dynamically generated by using ng-repeat:

```
<ion-content>

    <div class="matchList">

        <div class="matchListItem" ng-repeat="match in matchData">

            <div class="home-team-name">
                {{match.Team1.TeamName}}
            </div>

            <div class="tip-input">
                <input type="text" style="border:1px solid #CCC; width:100%; height:23px; padding-left:4px;" />
            </div>

            <div class="tip-center">
                <center>:</center>
            </div>

            <div class="tip-input">
                <input type="text" style="border:1px solid #CCC; width:100%; height:23px; padding-left:4px;" />
            </div>

            <div class="guest-team-name">
                {{match.Team2.TeamName}}
            </div>

            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="save-button">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="save()">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

It is a tip game for a Football League. So there are two text boxes for each match of a matchday. I want to send the values of the text boxes to a php file. I know I can do something like this:

```
$scope.save = function () {

    $http.get('http://localhost/saveTips.php?data=' + data).then(function (response) {
        $scope.doesItWork = response.data;
    })

}
```

But how can I save the values of each textbox in the data variable to send that to the php file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to atribute models to the fields, allowing accessing data on the controller. 
You could do something as simple as storing the data on an array (a new one, or even the same array you did the ng-repeat, as seen in this simple example.)

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="input in inputs" ng-model="input.model" />
```

[Live JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73Loumze/)

If you like to see a more complicated example let me know, but I think you can get the ideia.

Comment: What must I do when I want to submit the value of the first textbox? I tried it with:

var firstValue = $scope.matchData[0].model;

    $scope.save = function () {

        $http.get('http://localhost/saveTips.php?data=' + firstValue).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })

    }

But it says:

Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: I've updated a little the example, [take a look at it](http://jsfiddle.net/73Loumze/1/). Let me know if this isn't what you are looking for. @Nono

Answer (score 0):

You would use `ng-model` on each input, then just post the array to the server. On the server you would have to accept an array of `match` objects.

Assuming your `match` object is

```
match:{
  Team1:{
    TeamName:'',
    InputValue:''
  },
  Team2:{
    TeamName:'',
    InputValue:''
  }
}
```

Then your inputs would have `ng-model="match.Team1.InputValue"` (or Team2)

Also, you should use `$http.post('http://localhost/saveTips.php', data)` and change your php file to accept a POST request, since it looks like you're saving data.